# Given an array of arguments, how do I send those arguments to a particular function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, function, arguments

Forgive the beginner question, but say I have an array:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

And a function somewhere; let's say it's an instance function:

```
class Ilike
  def turtles(*args)
    puts args.inspect
  end
end
```

How do I invoke `Ilike.turtles` with `a` as if I were calling `(Ilike.new).turtles(1,2,3)`.

I'm familiar with `send`, but this doesn't seem to translate an array into an argument list.

A parallel of what I'm looking for is the Javascript `apply`, which is equivalent to `call` but converts the array into an argument list.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

As you know, when you define a method, you can use the `*` to turn a list of arguments into an array. Similarly when you call a method you can use the `*` to turn an array into a list of arguments. So in your example you can just do:

```
Ilike.new.turtles(*a)
```

Comment: Fantastic. Based on your excellent answer, I've found a more thorough account of this technique in [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Variable_Length_Argument_List.2C_Asterisk_Operator). This is actually perfectly reasonable given the parallel notation going the other other way. Oh, Ruby indeed. I've also noticed that you can prepend your own arguments without awkward `a.unshift` fidgeting by using `Ilike.new.turtles(1,2,3,*a)`, although postpending seems to require such a manoeuver.

Comment: @StevenXu In Ruby 1.9 you can also splat for 'postpending'. `a=[1,2]; b=[4,5]; p(0,*a,3,*b,6) #=> "0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6"`

Comment: This is a fun technique: `some_func(*'some string of args'.split)`