# Improving Rails.cache.write by setting key-value pairs asynchronously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, worker, memcachier

I am currently thinking about improving the performance of `Rails.cache.write` when using dalli to write items to the [memcachier](https://addons.heroku.com/memcachier) cloud.

The stack, as it relates to caching, is currently:

`heroku, memcachier heroku addon, dalli 2.6.4, rails 3.0.19`

I am using newrelic for performance monitoring.

I am currently fetching "active students" for a given logged in user, represented by a `BusinessUser` instance, when its `active_students` method is called from a controller handling a request that requires a list of "active students":

```
class BusinessUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def active_students
    Rails.cache.fetch("/studio/#{self.id}/students") do
      customer_users.active_by_name
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

After looking at newrelic, I've basically narrowed down one big performance hit for the app in setting key values on memcachier. It takes an average of **225ms** every time. Further, it looks like setting memcache key values blocks the main thread and eventually disrupts the request queue. Obviously this is undesirable, especially when the whole point of the caching strategy is to *reduce* performance bottlenecks.

In addition, I've benchmarked the cache storage with plain dalli, and Rails.cache.write for 1000 cache sets of the same value:

```
heroku run console -a {app-name-redacted}
irb(main):001:0> require 'dalli'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> cache = Dalli::Client.new(ENV["MEMCACHIER_SERVERS"].split(","),
irb(main):003:1*                     {:username => ENV["MEMCACHIER_USERNAME"],
irb(main):004:2*                      :password => ENV["MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD"],
irb(main):005:2*                      :failover => true,
irb(main):006:2*                      :socket_timeout => 1.5,
irb(main):007:2*                      :socket_failure_delay => 0.2
irb(main):008:2>                     })
=> #<Dalli::Client:0x00000006686ce8 @servers=["server-redacted:11211"], @options={:username=>"username-redacted", :password=>"password-redacted", :failover=>true, :socket_timeout=>1.5, :socket_failure_delay=>0.2}, @ring=nil>
irb(main):009:0> require 'benchmark'
=> false
irb(main):010:0> n = 1000
=> 1000
irb(main):011:0> Benchmark.bm do |x|
irb(main):012:1*   x.report { n.times do ; cache.set("foo", "bar") ; end }
irb(main):013:1>   x.report { n.times do ; Rails.cache.write("foo", "bar") ; end }
irb(main):014:1> end
       user     system      total        real
 Dalli::Server#connect server-redacted:11211
Dalli/SASL authenticating as username-redacted
Dalli/SASL: username-redacted
  0.090000   0.050000   0.140000 (  2.066113)

Dalli::Server#connect server-redacted:11211
Dalli/SASL authenticating as username-redacted
Dalli/SASL: username-redacted

  0.100000   0.070000   0.170000 (  2.108364)
```

With plain dalli `cache.set`, we are using 2.066113s to write 1000 entries into the cache, for an average `cache.set` time of 2.06ms.

With `Rails.cache.write`, we are using 2.108364s to write 1000 entries into the cache, for an average `Rails.cache.write` time of 2.11ms.

⇒ It seems like the problem is not with memcachier, but simply with the amount of data that we are attempting to store.

According to [the docs for the #fetch method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch), it looks like it would not be the way I want to go, if I want to throw cache sets into a separate thread or a worker, because I can't split out the `write` from the `read` - and self-evidently, I don't want to be reading asynchronously.

Is it possible to reduce the bottleneck by throwing `Rails.cache.write` into a worker, when setting key values? Or, **more generally**, is there a better pattern to do this, so that I am not blocking the main thread every time I want to perform a `Rails.cache.write`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two factors that would contribute to overall latency under normal circumstances: client side marshalling/compression and network bandwidth.

Dalli mashalls and optionally compresses the data, which could be quite expensive. Here are some benchmarks of Marshalling and compressing a list of random characters (a kind of artificial list of user ids or something like that). In both cases the resulting value is around 200KB. Both benchmarks were run on a Heroku dyno - performance will obviously depend on the CPU and load of the machine:

```
irb> val = (1..50000).to_a.map! {rand(255).chr}; nil
# a list of 50000 single character strings
irb> Marshal.dump(val).size
275832
# OK, so roughly 200K. How long does it take to perform this operation
# before even starting to talk to MemCachier?
irb> Benchmark.measure { Marshal.dump(val) }
=>   0.040000   0.000000   0.040000 (  0.044568)
# so about 45ms, and this scales roughly linearly with the length of the list.


irb> val = (1..100000).to_a; nil # a list of 100000 integers
irb> Zlib::Deflate.deflate(Marshal.dump(val)).size
177535
# OK, so roughly 200K. How long does it take to perform this operation
irb>  Benchmark.measure { Zlib::Deflate.deflate(Marshal.dump(val)) }
=>   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.145672)
```

So we're basically seeing anywhere from a 40ms to 150ms performance hit just for Marshaling and/or zipping data. Marshalling a String will be much cheaper, while marshalling something like a complex object will be more expensive. Zipping depends on the size of the data, but also on the redundancy of the data. For example, zipping a 1MB string of all "a" characters takes merely about 10ms.

Network bandwidth will play some of a role here, but not a very significant one. MemCachier has a 1MB limit on values, which would take approximately 20ms to transfer to/from MemCachier:

```
irb(main):036:0> Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { c.set("h", val, 0, :raw => true) } }
=>   0.250000  11.620000  11.870000 ( 21.284664)
```

This amounts to about 400Mbps (1MB * 8MB/Mb * (1000ms/s / 20ms)), which makes sense. However, for even a relatively large, but still smaller value of 200KB, we'd expect a 5x speedup:

```
irb(main):039:0> val = "a" * (1024 * 200); val.size
=> 204800
irb(main):040:0> Benchmark.measure { 1000.times { c.set("h", val, 0, :raw => true) } }
=>   0.160000   2.890000   3.050000 (  5.954258)
```

So, there are several things you might be able to do to get some speedup:

1. Use a faster marshalling mechanism. For example, using `Array#pack("L*")` to encode a list of 50,000 32-bit unsigned integers (like in the very first benchmark) into a string of length 200,000 (4 bytes for each integer), takes only 2ms rather than 40ms. Using compression with the same marshalling scheme, to get a similar sized value is also very fast (about 2ms as well), but the compression doesn't do anything useful on random data anymore (Ruby's Marshal produces a fairly redundant String even on a list of random integers).
2. Use smaller values. This would probably require deep application changes, but if you don't really *need* the whole list, you should be setting it. For example, the memcache protocol has `append` and `prepend` operations. If you are only ever adding new things to a long list, you could use those operations instead.

Finally, as suggested, removing the set/gets from the critical path would prevent any delays from affecting HTTP request latency. You still have to get the data to the worker, so it's important that if you're using something like a work queue, the message you send to the worker should only contain instructions on which data to construct rather than the data itself (or you're in the same hole again, just with a different system). A very lightweight (in terms of coding effort) would be to simply fork a process:

```
mylist = Student.where(...).all.map!(&:id)
...I need to update memcache with the new list of students...
fork do
  # Have to create a new Dalli client
  client = Dalli::Client.new
  client.set("mylistkey", mylist)
  # this will block for the same time as before, but is running in a separate process
end
```

I haven't benchmarked a full example, but since you're not `exec`ing, and Linux fork is copy-on-write, the overhead of the fork call itself should be minimal. On my machine, it's about 500us (that's **micro**-seconds not milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails.cache.write to prefetch and store data in cache with workers (e.g. Sidekiq) is what I've seen at high volumes. Of course there is a trade off between speed and the money you want to spend. Think about:

- the most used paths in your app (is `active_students` accessed often?);
- what to store (just IDs or the entire objects or further down the chain);
- if you can optimize that query (n+1?).

Also, if you really need speed, consider using a dedicated memcache service, instead of a Heroku add-on.

Comment: First, thanks for pointing out sidekiq. I love that sidekiq just works on heroku (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#heroku) 

However, Why do you think that there's a clear tradeoff between speed and money? For instance, with iron.io's workers, the cost of 200 worker hours is free. With sidekiq, it looks like it would be "free" as well, because we wouldn't be using heroku's workers? Am I missing something?

And yes, `active_students` is accessed *very* often.

Comment: @zealoushacker I was also meaning cost of cache memory: it's not free! :) The more you cache, the less you access DB, but the more you spend. Sidekiq consumers are still run by workers, so you would need to use at least 1 worker. Or you can use the hack you linked.

Comment: PS: I never used iron.io, but it seems it hosts the Sidekiq server along with the consumers ("workers"), so you wouldn't need Heroku workers.