# RSpec & Custom matcher with multiple arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I'm trying to create a custom matcher for my tests in RoR using RSpec.

```
  define :be_accessible do |attributes|
    attributes = attributes.is_a?(Array) ? attributes : [attributes]
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      match do |response|
        response.class.accessible_attributes.include?(attribute)
      end
      description { "#{attribute} should be accessible" }
      failure_message_for_should { "#{attribute} should be accessible" }
      failure_message_for_should_not { "#{attribute} should not be accessible" }
    end
  end
```

I want to be able to write something like the following in my tests:

```
...
should be_accessible(:name, :surname, :description)
...
```

but with the matcher defined above, I **must** pass an array of symbols instead of symbols separated by commas otherwise the test examines only the first symbol.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an answer that should match your very first need : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4643289/582863. Anyway, I'm curious about your intention here... Do you just want to reduce the number of lines in your rspec test files, or are your testing complex accessibilities on model attributes?

Comment: The problem with the link you provided is that this is not a "regular" def method so I can't use the *. Answering your question, I just want to reduce my rspec's lines :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it work this way :

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_accessible do |*attributes|
  match do |response|

    description { "#{attributes.inspect} be accessible" }

    attributes.each do |attribute|
      failure_message_for_should { "#{attribute} should be accessible" }
      failure_message_for_should_not { "#{attribute} should not be accessible" }

      break false unless response.class.accessible_attributes.include?(attribute)
    end
  end
end
```

I inverted the `match` and the `each` loop. I think this is the way Rspec expect it to be, as the block given to the `match` method is the one executed by Rspec abstract matcher (I guess).

By defining the block with `|*attributes|`, it takes the list of parameters and turn it into an `Array`.

So calling `should be_accessible(:name, :surname, :description)` will work.

By the way, if you just want to check for the existence of attributes, a simple

```
should respond_to(:name, :surname, :description)
```

works as well. But it does not looks like for mass-assignement aspect.

Comment: It works, thanx for your time! I want to check for mass assignment so your solution is the one I need.

Comment: This really helped me however, when I adapted this example for my own situation I found it only works for positive expectations (does not work for should_not as-is).  I had to create separate `match_for_should` and `match_for_should_not` blocks like detailed here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/custom-matchers/define-matcher#matcher-with-separate-logic-for-should-and-should-not